# UrlImageViewCallback : called only when when image loading is successfull

Tags: android, callback, urlimageviewhelper

I am using the amazing UrlImageViewHelper library from koush https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

The problem that I am currently facing is that the helper only notify when an iMage is succesfully loaded, according to the callback documentation:

> callback An instance of UrlImageViewCallback that is called when the
>   image successfully finishes loading. This value can be null.

```
UrlImageViewCallback myCallback = new UrlImageViewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Drawable loadedDrawable,
            String url, boolean loadedFromCache) {
```

I just wanted to know how it would be possible to be notified when an ImageView is not loaded. (server didn't answer, or wrong url)

Thank a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like I had to create my own callback:

```
public interface UrlImageViewCallback {
    void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Drawable loadedDrawable, String url, boolean loadedFromCache);
    void onFail(ImageView imageView, String url);
}
```

Working fine now.

Comment: Can i know how to set this callback for the image view ?

Comment: Thanks to this change https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper/commit/50322a6475344c597c7fc63856d6a556d81d066a you will receive a null in onLoaded callback.